# How to say G-d's names, when reading psukim from targum?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, shnayim-mikra

There is prohibition to say G-d's names in vain. Ashkenazim have the practice not to say Hashem's name when reading a pasuk in the gemara or when reading a half pasuk. [see here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Not_Saying_Hashem%27s_Name_in_Vain)

What about reading *psukim* from *targum*? Is person aloud to say them as they are or he should replace them by *Hashem*, etc?